# Java mail from virtual mail Id like node mailer

Tags: java, email

I have a corporate email and SMTP host for that. I would like to send email using Java.

i.e My email Id is `1234@example.com` and password is `password`.

I like to send email to others using this id, but from email should be virtual like `noreply@example.com`

I tried following, using javax mail

```
public class SendMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "1234@example.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.example.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("noreply@example.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("someone@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                    + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I set `messege.setFrom` to other user Id, but I checked the mail. It shows from address as 1234@example.com only.

I dont want to create noreply@example.com, Is this possible in Java to send email like this. this is available in node mailer.

Comment: Do you find `noreply@example.com` in any other header of the received message ?

Comment: Not Sure but can you try  message.setSender(new InternetAddress("no-reply@domain.com", "Sender Name"));

Comment: No Its not available anywhere Peter

Comment: @JQuery i guess your SMTP host stripped it out and takes user account as from address.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
props.put("mail.from", "noreply@example.com");
```

into your properties. It should change MAIL FROM message at the beginning of the SMTP Transaction.